# Add trigger to SQLAlchemy Base Class

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm making a SQLAlchemy base class for a new Postgres database and want to have bookkeeping fields incorporated into it. Specifically, I want to have two columns for `modified_at` and `modified_by` that are updated automatically. I was able to find out how to do this for individual tables, but it seems like making this part of the base class is trickier.

My first thought was to try and leverage the `declared_attr` functionality, but I don't actually want to make the triggers an attribute in the model so that seems incorrect. Then I looked at adding the trigger using `event.listen`:

```
trigger = """
CREATE TRIGGER update_{table_name}_modified
BEFORE UPDATE ON {table_name}
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified_columns()
"""

def create_modified_trigger(target, connection, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(target, 'name'):
        connection.execute(modified_trigger.format(table_name=target.name))

Base = declarative_base()

event.listen(Base.metadata,'after_create', create_modified_trigger)
```

I thought I could find `table_name` using the `target` parameter as shown [in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents) but when used with `Base.metadata` it returns `MetaData(bind=None)` rather than a table.

I would strongly prefer to have this functionality as part of the Base rather than including it in migrations or externally to reduce the chance of someone forgetting to add the triggers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to sort this out with the help of a coworker. The returned `MetaData` object did in fact have a list of tables. Here is the working code:

```
modified_trigger = """
CREATE TRIGGER update_{table_name}_modified
BEFORE UPDATE ON {table_name}
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified_columns()
"""

def create_modified_trigger(target, connection, **kwargs):
    """
    This is used to add bookkeeping triggers after a table is created. It hooks
    into the SQLAlchemy event system. It expects the target to be an instance of
    MetaData.
    """
    for key in target.tables:
        table = target.tables[key]
        connection.execute(modified_trigger.format(table_name=table.name))

Base = declarative_base()

event.listen(Base.metadata, 'after_create', create_modified_trigger)
```